# Why my MVC 3 form post refreshes the page after submit?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have this form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "MyController", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmEdit" })) {
<input type="text" id="Title" value="Adam" />
}
```

Here is the jquery:

```
  $(function () {
        $('#frmEdit').submit(function () {
            //read form values            
            //verify req fields
            if (isValid) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: this.action,
                    type: this.method,
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    beforeSend: SpinWheel(l),
                    success: function (result) {
                        if (result.s == 'OK') {
                            alert("Success Updated");                                                    
                        }
                        else {
                            Alert("Sorry! Update failed.");
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) { alert('Error');}
                });
            }
            return false;
        });

    });
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Update(FormCollection album)
{
   return Json(new { s = "OK" });
}
```

The form has a modal inside it. When I click a link in parent page, the modal is launched.
In the modal I have the form with a submit button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a call to `preventDefault()` on the `event` passed in:

```
$('#frmEdit').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    ....
});
```

---

bad copy/paste? `alert(Error');`

If so, this could be the reason it wasn't hitting the `return false;` at the end of your `submit` event

Comment: This seems not refreshing. Still looking for other issues.